# aiohttp Proxy: Why are the GET requests IPs rotating, but not the other methods?

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, aiohttp

I'm having this weird issue where everytime I make a GET request using aiohttp, it does use rotating IPs with my proxy configured. But when I try other kind of methods to make the request (POST, PUT, PATCH...), it remains with the same IP at every request, which is quite annoying in this case.

I found a potential solution where I have to re-create a session everytime I make one of those requests (`async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:`), but creating a client for each of them is consuming a lot of time.

```
resp = await session.request('GET', url='https://httpbin.org/get', proxy=Proxy.LIST, headers=headers, **kwargs)
resp.raise_for_status()
data = await resp.json()
print(data)
```

Working rotation

```
resp = await session.request('POST', url='https://httpbin.org/post', proxy=Proxy.LIST, headers=headers, **kwargs)
resp.raise_for_status()
data = await resp.json()
print(data)
```

Non-working rotation

The Proxy.LIST variable is a single address, which should give me access to rotating IPs at each request. I'm using SmartProxy.

Comment: maybe `SmartProxy` rotates only for `GET`? Or maybe you have to pay to rotate with `POST`, etc.

Comment: I've seen with their support, but it doesn't seem to come from them, since the IP does rotate whenever I restart a session with POST, which isn't necessary using GET.

Comment: it may automatically rotate IP because you restart session - server may create new pool of IPs. So it can still be the same problem that they rotate only when you use GET